# What causes a context type error when using axios in React with TypeScript and how to fix it?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props, react-context

I want to write context with typescript. So here api is drawn through axios and written to the screen with cards. But it gives an error about the context type, how can I eliminate it?

My Error is : Type '{ data: ProductList | undefined; setData: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<ProductList | undefined>>; }' is not assignable to type 'productType[]'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'data' does not exist in type 'productType[]'.

```
import axios from "axios";
import { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
interface ContextChildrenProps {
    children: JSX.Element
}

export interface SingleProduct {
    title: string,
    description: string,
    thumbnail: string
}

export interface productType {
    product: SingleProduct
}

export interface ProductList {
    data: productType[]
}

export const GlobalProductsContext = createContext<productType[] | null>({} as productType[])

export const ProductsContextProvider = ({ children }: ContextChildrenProps) => {

    const [data, setData] = useState<ProductList>()

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('https://fakestoreapi.com/products')
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res)
                setData(res.data)
            })

    }, [])

    return (
        <GlobalProductsContext.Provider value={{ data, setData }}>
            {children}
        </GlobalProductsContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

```js
import React from 'react'
import { productType } from '../context/GlobalData'

const SingleCard = ({ product }: productType) => {
    return (
        <>
            <div className="col-lg-4 p-2" data-aos="flip-left">
                <div className="card" style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}>
                    <img src={product.thumbnail} className="card-img-top" alt="..." />
                    <div className="card-body">
                        <h5 className="card-title">{product.title}</h5>
                        <p className="card-text">{product.description}</p>
                        <a href="#" className="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default SingleCard
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TS type of context value is not correct.

Try:

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";

interface ContextChildrenProps {
  children: JSX.Element
}

export interface SingleProduct {
  title: string,
  description: string,
  thumbnail: string
}

type ProductContext = {
  data: SingleProduct[];
  setData: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<SingleProduct[]>>
}

export const GlobalProductsContext = createContext<ProductContext>({ data: [], setData: () => { } })

export const ProductsContextProvider = ({ children }: ContextChildrenProps) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<SingleProduct[]>([])

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('https://fakestoreapi.com/products')
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
        setData(res.data)
      })

  }, [])

  return (
    <GlobalProductsContext.Provider value={{ data, setData }}>
      {children}
    </GlobalProductsContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Comment: Okay, but now where i mapping the data this error coming :
Type 'ProductType' is missing the following properties from type 'SingleProduct': title, description, thumbnail
'data' is possibly 'undefined'.

Comment: @PashaMammadov `SingleProduct` type is enough, the `ProductType` and `ProductList` types are unnecessary in your example.

Comment: Okay, everything is clear, thanks you very much, but i have a last question. Can we change state value undefined? 
Because where i want to use this state(data) i have error like this --> 'data' is possibly 'undefined'.

Comment: @PashaMammadov You can give a default value like empty array `[]` instead of `undefined`